# WPF Animation starts but shows too late

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, animation

I am building some WPF controls using .Net 4.0. One of these controls, called LoadingPane, is a custom control derived from ContentControl.
The only job of this LoadingPane control is to show a semi-transparent layer over it's contained content when it's IsLoading property is set to true.
I use some animations to do fade-in, fade-out when the IsLoading value changes.
When the overlay is shown an animation rotates a circle of elipses.

So far, so good. This all works very nicely. But here's my problem: when i set the Loading property to true the animation isn't shown directly. It takes about half a second. In this time the fade-in animation has already run, so the opacity effectively goes from 0 to 1 in one step.

Here's my animation code:

```xml
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsLoading"
             Value="True">
        <Trigger.EnterActions>
            <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="EndAnimateLoadingCanvas" />
            <BeginStoryboard Name="AnimateLoadingCanvas">
                <Storyboard FillBehavior="Stop">
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetName="MyViewBoxje"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                    <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                     Duration="00:00:00.5"
                                     Storyboard.TargetName="MyViewBoxje"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                     To="1" />

                    <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                     Duration="00:00:02"
                                     Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedRotateTransform"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                     From="360"
                                     To="0"
                                     RepeatBehavior="Forever" />

                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </Trigger.EnterActions>
        <Trigger.ExitActions>
            <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="AnimateLoadingCanvas" />
            <BeginStoryboard Name="EndAnimateLoadingCanvas">
                <Storyboard FillBehavior="Stop">
                    <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                     Duration="00:00:00.5"
                                     Storyboard.TargetName="MyViewBoxje"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                     To="0" />
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00.5"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetName="MyViewBoxje"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </Trigger.ExitActions>
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

The strange thing is, when i use this control in a test window and i click the Loading checkbox repeatedly (and before the animation has finished) then the fade-in/fade-out animation does work as i expect it to work.

Can anyone help? Thanx in advance!

Comment: I had this exact same issue (albeit under a different circumstance).  An animation I had which ran when a Silverlight app loaded never displayed the animation the *first* time.  But subsequent loads thereafter did work.  Terminating and starting the app again I would get the same behaviour.  Never found an answer so +1 =)

Comment: Bounty added, maybe we can get an answer for it that way.  In essence, I think the question is how to prevent loadup animations being skipped, preferably without some form of workaround that enforces a first time blocking timer event?

Comment: +1 like Smudge. Having the same issues with SL.

Comment: Why don´t you use a BusyIndicator and style it your way?

Comment: I'd count that as a work around @Jehof. =)  I'm sure we've all seen websites and applications which, when you load them up are blank or similar, but then various aspects of the page fade into view.  My opinion is that is a stylish/professional look, and it's a nuisance that, as-is, the same effect would not work because the page would load the first time completely in view with no fade animations.  Perhaps the answer is to move some aspects to async?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out after reading Isak's answer.
Sorry to say that his answer did not help in my case but he got me going in the right direction.

The reason that the first fade-in did not seem to work was because my containing viewbox had it's visibility set to collapsed the whole time the fade-in animation was performed.
This was caused by the ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames:

```
    DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

There was no duration specified and the single key frame specified was animated too late.

Adding

```
Duration="00:00:00"
```

solved my problem.

Thanks to you all helping!

Comment: That wasn't the case for me, so although I'll understand you marking your own answer as the answer, I'll be awarding the bounty to Isak for his complete example which appears to work and will serve as a good reference if I have this same issue in the future.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to see exactly what the problem is without seeing the rest of the code but my guess is that it has to do with the start values of the animated properties.

I implemented a custom control in WPF with a rectangle inside a viewbox and used the triggers + storyboards from the question to see the effect. Indeed, my first attempt did not fade in nor fade out.

What I did to solve it was by specifying `From` values in the animations so that they work regardless of what the original value of the DP's were:

```
<DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00"
      Duration="00:00:00.5"
      Storyboard.TargetName="MyViewBoxje"
      Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
      From="0"
      To="1" />
```

Notice `From="0"` in the above animation. The end storyboard was modified the same way, to go from 1 to 0.

For completeness I set the opacity to `0` on the definition of the viewbox element inside the ControlTemplate as well.

---

Here is the complete source code for the relevant parts. The control is a standard WPF custom control inheriting from [Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.aspx). It has a single dependency property called `IsLoading` (`bool`) which defaults to `false`:

```
public bool IsLoading
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsLoadingProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsLoadingProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsLoading.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsLoadingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsLoading", typeof(bool), typeof(LoadingControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));
```

**ControlTemplate** - Defined in generic.xaml in the style for `{x:Type local:LoadingControl}`

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:LoadingControl}">
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsLoading" Value="True">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="EndAnimateLoadingCanvas" />
                <BeginStoryboard Name="AnimateLoadingCanvas">
                    <Storyboard FillBehavior="Stop">
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                   Storyboard.TargetName="MyViewBoxje"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                        <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                     Duration="00:00:00.5"
                                     Storyboard.TargetName="MyViewBoxje"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                     From="0"
                                     To="1" />

                        <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                         Duration="00:00:02"
                                         Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedRotateTransform"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                         From="360"
                                         To="0"
                                         RepeatBehavior="Forever" />

                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="AnimateLoadingCanvas" />
                <BeginStoryboard Name="EndAnimateLoadingCanvas">
                    <Storyboard FillBehavior="Stop">
                        <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                         Duration="00:00:00.5"
                                         Storyboard.TargetName="MyViewBoxje"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                         From="1"
                                        To="0" />
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00.5"
                                   Storyboard.TargetName="MyViewBoxje"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
        <Viewbox x:Name="MyViewBoxje" Opacity="0">
            <!-- BG with 0x50 alpha so that it's translucent event at 100% visibility -->
            <Grid Width="100" Height="100" Background="#50000000">
                <Rectangle Width="70" Height="20" Fill="Green" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="360" x:Name="AnimatedRotateTransform" />
                    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                </Rectangle>
            </Grid>
        </Viewbox>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I used in my main window like so:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <!-- All other stuff here ... -->

    <my:LoadingControl IsLoading="{Binding IsLoading}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
</Grid>
```

And to test it I had a ViewModel with a property `IsLoading` that is set as DataContext for the main window. And in the constructor of the ViewModel I set `IsLoading` to true and then start a timer that toggles the value of the property every 5 seconds:

```
public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    IsLoading = true;
    DispatcherTimer t = new DispatcherTimer();
    t.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    t.Tick += (s, e) => IsLoading = !IsLoading;
    t.Start();
}
```

Comment: Looks like a winner, though if you don't mind posting the full thing that would be ace.  The silverlight project I failed with (ref a comment on the OP) I've long since lost hold of.  Perhaps @Elad Katz can confirm too? =)

Comment: Thanks Isak, this will be a handy reference in the future.  I'll award bounty once it allows me.